# Поменять местами старшие 8 бит и младшие 8 бит местами числа типа short (Java)

Tags: java, битовые-операции

Как поменять местами старшие 8 бит и младшие 8 бит числа типа short? Применяю битовые сдвиги, но результат всегда получается некорректный.

Comment: Приведите пример того что вы делаете, результат и объяснение того почему вы считаете его некорректным.

Comment: Небось, используете `>>` вместо `>>>`?